# Spring 5 WebClient- retrieve method not getting recognized with groovy but works with java

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am using groovy, spring5, springboot2 and i was trying to  replace Resttemplate with WebClient inorder to makes some synchronous HTTP(REST) calls. Retrieve() in `webClient.get().uri("").retrieve()` is not getting recognized(compilation error) in .groovy while the same code works in .java

WebClientJava.java

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

public class WebClientJava {

    String retriever(){

        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

       String responsess =  webClient.get().uri("").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();


        return responsess;
    }
}
```

WebClientGroovy.groovy

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient

class WebClientGroovy {

    String retriever(){

        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create()

        WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec responsess = webClient.get().uri("").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block()

        return responsess
    }
}
```

i expect it work with groovy as it is working with java. Does any one encounter or has any thoughts?

Comment: The Groovy code compiles for me. Can you share a complete and minimal example that reproduces the compilation problem?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Here is the sample project and am using **intellij** as my IDE https://github.com/BhargavModepalli/WebClinet-Example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/WebClinetExample/WebClinetGroovy.groovy#L11

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be caused by a bug in IntelliJ IDEA as the sample project builds successfully on the command line with Maven.

The `uri` method returns `S` with `S` being defined as `S extends RequestHeadersSpec<?>`. The IDE appears to be unable to cope with this and believes it's dealing with a `?` which it treats as `java.lang.Object`. I would recommend [reporting the problem to JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

In the meantime, you can work around the problem by casting the return from `uri`:

```
String responses = ((WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec)webClient.get().uri(""))
        .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block()
```